# how to fetch details from multiple domain

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I am trying to create AD report in html via powershell but unable to fetch details from multiple domain,

below is my code,

```
# HTML Style
$a = "<style>"
$a = $a + "BODY{background-color:SkyBlue;font-family: calibri; font-size: 10pt;}"
$a = $a + "TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: grey;border-collapse: collapse;}"
$a = $a + "TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 5px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}"
$a = $a + "TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 5px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}"
$a = $a + "</style>"


# Query Range
$dt = (get-date).adddays(-3)

# Domain Selection
$Domains = 'test1.test.com' , 'test2.testuat.com'

ForEach ($domain in $Domains) {

$report += get-aduser -Server $domain -filter 'whencreated -ge $dt' -Properties * | 

# Attributes selection
select whenCreated,
SamAccountName,
GivenName,
Surname,
DisplayName,
Description,
EmployeeID,
mail,
Office,
City,
Title,
Department,
Company,
ScriptPath,
@{name=”MemberOf”;expression={$_.memberof -join “;”}}
}
$report | convertto-html -head $a | Out-File C:\scripts\ad.html
Invoke-Expression C:\scripts\ad.html
```

Comment: What does "unable to fetch details" mean? You get an error or an empty list or what? What credentials are you using? Are the domains in the same forest? Please, provide some more details.

Comment: your $a variable is always rewritten at the top. don't always write `$a = x`, instead put it in a script block `$a = { All HTML Text in here }`, then on the foreach loop you write `foreach ())` but it should be `foreach()`. in the `get-aduser` part you dont need to put the `$domain` in a scriptblock, and the filter has to be in singlequotes, not in a scriptblock. so your code would be `get-aduser -server $domain -filter 'whencreated -ge $dt' -properites * | #other stuff` clear this in your code, try it again and see if it works.

Comment: @iPath hi, i am getting output for only one domain, and both the domains are in same forest.

Comment: @SimonS thanks for the suggestion, will test by tomorrow and let you know

Answer (score 1):

Everytime this pipeline is executed:

```
convertto-html -head $a | Out-File C:\scripts\ad.html
```

you generate *a whole new html document* and the file (`C:\scripts\ad.html`) is being overwritten.

Replace the `foreach(){}` loop with the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet and move the `|ConvertTo-Html |Out-File` commands *outside* the loop:

```
$Domains |ForEach-Object {
  $Domain = $_
  Get-ADUser -Server $domain -Filter {whencreated -ge $dt} -Properties * | Select-Object whenCreated # and so on.
} |ConvertTo-Html -Head $a |Out-File C:\scripts\ad.html
```

Comment: -append parameter should do

Comment: Thanks @Mathias R. Jessen & strongline your suggestion were helpful